# TokenAware Policy in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

When using token aware policy as Load Balancing Policy in Cassandra do all the  queries are automatically send over the correct node (which contains the replica eg select * from Table where partionkey = something, will automatically get the hash and go to the correct replica) or I have to use token() function with all my queries ?

Answer (score 6):

That is correct. The `TokenAwarePolicy` will allow the driver to prefer a replica for the given partition key as the coordinator for the request if possible.

Additional information about load balancing with the Java driver is available on the [LoadBalancingPolicy API page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/LoadBalancingPolicy.html).

Specifically, the API documentation for `TokenAwarePolicy` is [available here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/TokenAwarePolicy.html).

Comment: So I don't need to make changes in my  current code just change the policy to token aware and it will automatically convert the partition key and query the  appropriate replica?

Comment: Yep, you configure the policy in your code but the actual node selection continues to be automatic. Make sure you're not using the batch keyword or queries for different token ranges will be routed together.